# Will my pets get eaten by aliens?

Tags: insaniquarium-deluxe

I noticed that when the aliens appear they eat my fish if they get close. Will they just eat the guppies and the carnivores, or do they eat the pet fish as well (such as the snail, the swordfish, etc)?

Comment: Are your pets cows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No

Your pets won't ever get eaten. If aliens would eat the swordfish for example, he wouldn't be of any use.

The only things to ever get eaten is things you buy during levels. Things in your own aquarium are perfectly safe. So if you ever buy a color changing fish, it'll never die.